# Add dependency to jenkins job dsl

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to add a dependency to my seed job, but no matter what I try, I always get the exception in Jenkins that it can't find the classes that I import in my groovy job. I've tried adding the dependency as compile, testCompile, lib, everything in my build.gradle file, but it doesn't seem to do anything... I'm trying to import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml from the org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17 dependency.

Any idea on how I can somehow get jenkins to get a hold of that dependency when trying to execute that seed job?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify one thing - are you trying to use `org.yaml.snakeyaml` in your `Jenkinsfile` DSL file?

Comment: I've found a solution for it, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I've found the solution. I copied the dependency to a specific folder during the gradle build and added that to the additional classpath of the job dsl. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you might use [**Grape**](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html) to download any dependency directly from your `Jenkinsfile`. If you add

```
@Grab(group='org.yaml', module='snakeyaml', version='1.20')
```

on top of your `Jenkinsfile`, Jenkins pipeline will download this dependency and it will get available in your pipeline script.